# HTML CSS Printable 2 column table with repeatable row level th element

Tags: html, css, html-table, printing-web-page

I am trying to make something printable and have the requirements to have two columns 50% width, left half is some info, right half is details. The details may overflow into a second page when printing, or many pages. If that happens on every page I need the first column's info to print on the left side in the same spot.

I'm aware that html table can do this but for vertical tables which will make every page print with the table headers at the top.

```
@media print {
  thead {display: table-header-group;}
}
```

Trying to find a solution for this but for a horizontal table, where the headers are not in a thead, but a th on every row, unless there is some other solution that is more obvious that I have overlooked.

```
<table>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
      <th>Repeatable on every printable page info</td>
      <td>Long details content that could overflow into multiple pages.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```